# Ubuntu 12.10 blank after login -- images/icons can't be displayed

Tags: unity, gnome, compiz, gtk

I rebooted my 12.10  (Linux ubuntu 3.2.0-60-generic #91-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 03:55:18 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux) which has been running fine for many months after a Thunderbird update and found the icons had suddenly changed and a few were missing on the login screen.  After logging in the screen was blank, no background image, no launcher, no task bar.

I went into a shell and tried unity --reset and --reset-icons but that failed.
--reset produced:

```
WARNING: Unity currently default profile, so switching to metacity while resetting the values
Window manager warning: Failed to load theme "Ambiance": Line 195 character 94: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/metacity-1/trough_left.png'
unity-panel-service: no process found
Checking if settings need to be migrated ...no
Checking if internal files need to be migrated ...no
Backend     : gconf
Integration : true
Profile     : unity
Adding plugins
Initializing core options...done

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2800003

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2800007

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2e000b1

compiz (core) - Warn: failed to receive ConfigureNotify event on 0x2400005

Initializing composite options...done
Initializing opengl options...done
Initializing decor options...done
Initializing vpswitch options...done
Initializing snap options...done
Initializing mousepoll options...done
Initializing resize options...done
Initializing place options...done
Initializing move options...done
Initializing wall options...done
Initializing grid options...done
Initializing session options...done
Initializing gnomecompat options...done
Initializing animation options...done
Initializing fade options...done
Initializing unitymtgrabhandles options...done
Initializing workarounds options...done
Initializing scale options...done
compiz (expo) - Warn: failed to bind image to texture
Initializing expo options...done
Initializing ezoom options...done

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1516:46: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1521:55: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1525:58: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1529:55: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1533:64: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1537:67: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1595:73: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle_vertical.png'

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1612:64: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle.png'

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:769:55: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:773:55: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:777:67: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:781:64: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:785:64: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:789:76: Unrecognized image file format

(compiz:4230): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_client_add_dir: assertion `gconf_valid_key (dirname, NULL)' failed
WARN  2014-03-22 17:42:37 unity.favorites FavoriteStoreGSettings.cpp:139 Unable to load GDesktopAppInfo for 'ubiquity-gtkui.desktop'
ERROR 2014-03-22 17:42:37 nux.image GdkGraphics.cpp:68 Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/unity/5/dash_noise.png'
WARN  2014-03-22 17:42:37 nux.image GdkGraphics.cpp:80 No pixbuf loaded
Segmentation fault
```

I then reinstalled compiz, ubunutu-desktop, no change.  I was able to get "gnome-panel" up so I had some GUI but several icons are missing but the services are running.  The windows can not be resized and I am unable to save screen shots to anything, even though I can read/write via terminal.

When I launch firefox for example it generates a "sys_page_size=0" error and can not be resized properly.  I have to connect with the CLI to wifi because there seems to be no indicator for network-manager.

I do see a lot of these:

```
Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:773:55: Unrecognized image file form
```

/var/log/syslog shows:

```
Mar 22 05:45:28 ubuntu kernel: [  376.763327] compiz[3062]: segfault at 0 ip 013
8d46f sp bfa59ea0 error 4 in libunityshell.so[11b8000+2ff000]
Mar 22 05:45:31 ubuntu kernel: [  379.209530] compiz[3161]: segfault at 0 ip 015
5d46f sp bffc9200 error 4 in libunityshell.so[1388000+2ff000]
Mar 22 05:46:11 ubuntu kernel: [  418.939940] compiz[3353]: segfault at 0 ip 04f
5346f sp bfee65b0 error 4 in libunityshell.so[4d7e000+2ff000]
```

Any ideas?  I don't know what is going on here and my system is pretty hosed.  I would like to find a fix for this rather than download a new image which will take days if I'm lucky.  TIA.

### EDIT #1:

I've been running kernel 3.2.0-60 for months and I've dropped back to 3.2.0-59 but no change in the situation.

One thing I discovered is that GTK can no longer read images (png, jpg, etc.).  I can't open images that I know are valid and none of the desktop images seem to load:

```
(gnome-panel:2954): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1612:64: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle.png'
```

This could be part of the problem with why icons, task bar, etc. are failing to show.  Does anyone have an idea of what I could try to correct these problems?

For example if I try to view a known good JPG with eog from the cli I get this string of messages and EOG opens to a empty (black) image with an error "Unrecognized image file format".  The command errors are:

```
(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1516:46: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1521:55: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1525:58: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1529:55: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1533:64: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1537:67: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1595:73: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle_vertical.png'

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets.css:1612:64: Couldn't recognize the image file format for file '/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/assets/scrollbar_handle.png'

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:769:55: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:773:55: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:777:67: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:781:64: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:785:64: Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-widgets-backdrop.css:789:76: Unrecognized image file format

** (eog:3842): CRITICAL **: failed to load icon 'lpi-help': Unrecognized image file format

(eog:3842): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_icon_theme_load_icon: assertion `error == NULL || *error == NULL' failed

** (eog:3842): CRITICAL **: failed to load icon 'lpi-translate': Unrecognized image file format
```

### EDIT #2:

Mr. Lee was correct https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1295220 was one of my problems because I had to use gfvs before there was a ubuntu ppa for it.  This was causing part of my problem with images/icons missing.  However I still need to drop to a terminal and run "gnome-panel" to bring up the taskbar (no launcher appears, unable to resize or move windows) and running gnome-panel produces this error:

```
*** BUG ***
In pixman_region32_init_rect: Invalid rectangle passed
Set a breakpoint on '_pixman_log_error' to debug
**strong text**
```

At least it is mostly functional once I run gnome-panel.  However I'm not sure what is still wrong with Unity.  Not being able to resize or move windows or have at the left side launcher bar means something is still really confused.

### EDIT #3:

In the end Mr. Lee's solution via the bugfix and running "unity --reset" restored the desktop properly and now boots up properly without the help of gnome-panel.

Comment: I think it was a kernel upgrade that messed up your computer, because they are the one which are installed after/during reboot.You should consider rolling back to previous version of kernel.

Comment: No kernel updates were made, just a reboot.  See edit.

Comment: Check this answer [http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it][1] 


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: @FirstStrike thanks, but the machine boots fine.  The background graphic won't display and many of the icons are empty.  After logging on the screen is blank, but I can bring up gnome-panel via cli.  However the GTK won't recognize any image files as valid.  I did a "update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime" which fixed a few of the basic menu icons, but many are still broken and I can't view any images.  Unity won't seem to run either.

Comment: I used command `fbgrab` to make screenshot in such situations.

Comment: @user6972 do you see the same problem with other user or guest accounts?

Comment: Try this and tell me if it helps-At boot, select `Ubuntu Recovery mode` (Second Entry). Then select drop to root shell prompt. And type `startx` there. Does the X server load properly there?

Comment: It seems that the problem is with metacity. try reconfiguring metacity (dpkg-reconfigure metacity)or reinstalling it. it may help.

Comment: @rusty It is a system wide problem.  And Awal Garg tried this but x server fails to get lock and aborts.  This is probably an access issue.  I didn't try it as root.  Anyway I think this might be a glib problem so I'll try that next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hoepfully you haven't found [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk+3.0/+bug/1295220) and it works for you. Start from comment 15.

User is asked to post `dpkg -l | grep libglib`

Someone responded that

> You are using a version of glib2.0 that is incompatible with the
>   version of gdk-pixbuf Ubuntu 12.04. You probably installed it from a
>   PPA.
>
> You need to revert the glib2.0 packages to the versions that come with
>   Ubuntu 12.04 to solve your issue.

His solution was to run

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/gvfs-libmtp
sudo gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders --update-cache`

Hope this leads to a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks!  This brought my icons/images back.  However there is still no task bar or launcher.  I have to run gnome-panel to bring up the task bar (no launcher appears).  See edit.

Comment: If everything works well besides the fact that its not coming up on boot, you can add it to a separate script to start on boot. Are there other problems present besides that (and launcher)?

Comment: Alternatively, you can add gnome-panel to "Startup Applications"

Comment: it seems that running "unity --reset" might do the trick.  I'm able to resize/move windows and the launcher is back.

Comment: @user6972 about _"no launchers and panel appears"_, you should try enabling the Unity plugins.. in `ccsm` and enable the plugins under _Desktop -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin_

Comment: @rusty Actually I tried that first, but everything was configured ok with ccsm.  Perhaps something else got messed up when I was having problems with the glib and I tried unity --reset and it failed part way through.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but you can give it a try...

Open a terminal and back some of the directories as mentioned in the commands that follow:

```
mkdir ~/tmpbak
mv -rt ~/tmpbak ~/{.compiz-1,.gconf} ~/.config/{compiz-1,dconf}
```

Log-out and back in, and you should get the problem fixed.

Comment: I tried this, but it just generated a blue screen of death after login and sat there.  I hit ctrl-alt-f1 to drop into a terminal, restore the files and restart.  I should mention this is not a user specific problem but a system wide problem.

Comment: hmm.. can't say why you had the blue screen, for me that always gets the job done, resetting compiz and others.. (the deleted directories/config files always gets created in the next login) but I see the problems fixed, so cheers...